# How can I draw a line using SVG?

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

How can I draw a line connecting 2 images using SVG?. For example I want to draw a line to connect $1 and $2 (assuming $1 and $2 are images):

```
$1
    $2
```

And is Javascript required?

Thanks!

Comment: is javascript require? depends on how dynamic those images are

Comment: define dynamic please

Comment: not static, not at a known location at design time

Comment: Yeah not static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily [draw a line with SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/line) and position it between your images:

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
<svg width="100" height="100" viewPort="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <line x1="0" y1="20" x2="100" y2="80" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" />
</svg>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
```

Comment: what is viewport?

Comment: The viewport is the visible area of the SVG image. An SVG image can logically be as wide and high as you want, but only a certain part of the image can be visible at a time. The area that is visible is called the viewport

Comment: One last question, what does the 100 in "0 0 100 100" do?

Comment: first one is width, 2nd is height (left, top, width, height)

Comment: oh ok got it :)

Comment: @Cabbage you know there is a tool called google where you can search for such info and learn something by yourself, do you? :)

Comment: Oh no never knew that :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```html
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
```

For more SVG tag info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_line.asp)
Note that SVG tag may not work properly on `IE`, `Edge` and `Firefox`
Also you can use `jsPlumb` library  [Here](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can Draw a line between the two images like

```
<img scr="http://www.belutics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/sample-placeholder.png" alt="$1"/>
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
<img scr="http://www.belutics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/sample-placeholder.png" alt="$2"/>
```

and if you want to link line with images?
try to get it done with **CSS** relative property
you can find help [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: But wont position:relative leave a blank space?

Comment: not u can add a class to overwrite the space by using CSS positioning like [http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_absolute